# ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to parse some XML, but I get this error:

Error message:

There is an error in XML document (1, 1937). ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content

Here is the XML:

http://pastebin.com/9A1sh8x5

Here is my class:

http://pastebin.com/7MQQubeK

I am trying to comment out strongly typed classes, like TaxInfo, however, this doesn't appear to solve the issue. Could it be a city field or a field that's of type string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Schemas for 1 xml file? perhaps you should have 2 xml files returned

```
</OrderInfo>


-<OrderShippingProfileInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Id>52107962</Id>
```

Answer (score 1):

XML Schema has to begin with a  element in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'!

From XMLSpy